# Adding additional text to a textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I have a page where when a user clicks on a certain button it will add that value to the textbox. I got the text to add on to the textbox, but it always inserts the value into a newline. It seems to include the < p > element each time as well. Is there anyway to get the value to insert on the same line?

I don't know if it makes any difference but I am using tinyMCE with this textbox.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAddEmailAmount').click(function() {                             
            var text = $( "#<%= tbxEmailMsg.ClientID %>" ).val() + " Amount";
            $( "#<%= tbxEmailMsg.ClientID %>" ).val( text );


        });
    });
```

**.aspx**

```
<div class="Dialog" id="pnlEmailMsg">
        <div class="Content" style="width: 685px; margin: 10px auto 10px auto; background-color: #D3D3D3; padding: 15px 30px 30px 30px;">
            <h1>Edit Email Message</h1>
            <button type="button" id="btnAddEmailAmount">Amount</button><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEmailMsg" runat="server" Height="500px"
                ToolTip="500 characters max" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="645" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
            <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px">
                <button type="button" id="btnCloseEmailMsg">close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="DialogCoverall"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure how your input looks like, but did you try to use $.trim(text)?

Comment: It seems **asp:TextBox** generate complex component not only textarea, you should inspect element from browser to find textarea you want to add text on it